# How to traverse arbitrary json tree with fsharp

Tags: json, f#, traversal

Can someone show an example how to traverse an arbitrary json 
tree with fsharp. The structure of the tree is unknown at forehand.
It must be possible at every node to determine,
node name, value type (structure|array|leaf).
At a structure or array recursively descent again.

I was trying to use Newtonsoft.Json.Linq but could not find
some useful fsharp examples.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [JSON Parser in FSharp.Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonValue.html) to parse json string to JsonValue, which is a type representing an arbitary json tree.

You can find an example how to traverse it recursively here:
https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Json/JsonValue.fs#L62